# Jackson and java.sql.Time serialization / deserialization

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

Consider this property in an `Hibernate`-managed entity:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
@Column(name = "start_time")
private java.sql.Time startTime;
```

I post a `JSON`-object as `@RequestBody` to a Spring Controller which `Jackson` is supposed to map into an instance of the entity (pojo).

`Jackson` does apparently not manage to de-serialize the time-string into a  `java.sql.Time`, because I am getting this Exception:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Time,
problem: null
```

How can I instruct `Jackson` to understand what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to roll your own deserializer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Time;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class SqlTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Time> {

    @Override
    public Time deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return Time.valueOf(jp.getValueAsString() + ":00");
    }
}
```

And then in the entity:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
@JsonDeserialize(using = SqlTimeDeserializer.class)
@Column(name = "start_time")
private Time                startTime;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try `hh:mm:ss` time format of `java.sql.Time` instead of `hh:mm` format.
This will be better way to handle exception instead of overriding `JsonDeserializer` method.