# Can not construct instance of java.sql.Time

Tags: java, json, spring, jdbc

I am trying to post a request in json format with postman.

my json is:

```
{
    "bud_year":"123",
    "tran_ndate":"2073-10-10",
    "tran_edate":"17-JUL-14",
    "bank_code":"12an",
    "bank_accno":"123",
    "amount":"12351",
    "payment_name":"1122",
    "voucher_no":"123",
    "depositSlipNo":"123"
}
```

my model class

```
public class Params {
    private String bud_year;
    private String tran_ndate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Time tran_edate;
    private String bank_code;
    private String bank_accno;
    private Long amount;
    private String payment_name;
    private String voucher_no;
    private int depositSlipNo;

    /* getter setters */

}
```

controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savePayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void savePayment(@RequestBody PaymentParams paymentParams){
 paymentServices.savePayment(paymentParams);
}
```

The error is:

```
Could not read JSON document: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Time,
problem: null
Can not construct instance of java.sql.Time, problem: null
```

17-JUL-14 means 14 July 2017. How do I make `tran_edate` property in my model class to accept 17-JUL-14 as time value?

Comment: maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777194/jackson-and-java-sql-time-serialization-deserialization

Comment: probably this could solve my problem but i am not being able to call the method getValueAsString() . am i missing some dependency?

i can call other methods like getValueAsBoolean() etc.

Comment: Note that `java.sql.Time` is only time, not a date, while your example JSON shows that it is a date. Consider using a `java.time.LocalDate` instead, because `java.sql.Time` is clearly the wrong data type.